# Spring boot, Keycloak, React App: . How to handle the keycloak custom cancel button returns onAuthError access denied which returns empty page

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

The keycloak custom cancel button returns onAuthError access denied which returns an empty page. But it is not displaying the base URL. How to handle this in the React Client.

I am using a custom login ftl which is basically from the Keycloak login template with one more button for Cancel.
The keycloak custom cancel button returns onAuthError access denied which returns an empty page. But it is not displaying the base URL. How to handle this in the React Client. I am not getting any examples of handling the OnAuthError access denied with an empty page at the React client.